# CloudFirestore how to query large dataset?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I'm trying to query a dataset in cloud firestore which has 180k documents, but process is extremely long(70 seconds), in order to avoid this, should i split my collection to subcollections or is there anyway to make it more efficient ?

**QUERY FUNCTION**

```
Future getProfList(String uni, String department, bool asynCall) async {
  
  List<Academician> academicianList = [];
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('academicians')
      .where('university', isEqualTo: academicianFilter(uni))
      .where(stringCorrector('field'), isEqualTo: academicianFilter(department))
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
            academicianList.add(Academician.fromJson(element));
          }));
  asynCall = false;
  return academicianList;
}
```

**official doc**

According to https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html
my dataset shouldn't be problem here, and my result set is mostly 50-100 document.

> Uses collections and documents to structure and query data. This data
> model is familiar and intuitive for many developers. It also allows
> for expressive queries. Queries scale with the size of your result
> set, not the size of your data set, so you'll get the same performance
> fetching 1 result from a set of 100, or 100,000,000.

Comment: There should be no need to split the collection. Did you by any chance **add** the data from the same device you're running the query on?

Comment: yes, i added documents this morning and tried to run query from same device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore actually has a guarantee that the time it takes to execute a query depends on the amount of data that query returns, and not in any way on the amount of data that exists in the collection.

Unfortunately (as confirmed in the comments to your question) you're hitting an edge case here. This guarantee applies to queries run on the server, which is the most common use-case.

But since you added the data from the same device, you have a local database/cache on that device that also contains all these documents. And the performance guarantee does not apply for queries against the local cache.

So the easiest to get the expected performance is to clear the local cache, for example by uninstalling/reinstalling the app. Then you'll be in the more common scenario, where your query is sent to the server and takes time that is (only) proportional to the number of documents you retrieve.

Comment: Good to hear. Sorry that you bumped into this. It's so uncommon that we don't explicitly document it, as it's pretty confusing to explain - and incredibly counter-intuitive that queries against the local cache are slower than those against the server.